# Force client or server to restart SSL handshake (or expire SSL session)

Tags: ssl, handshake

I have a client (written in Java) which connects to an HTTPS server (the server written in Java also).

The client certificate and trusted certificates are stored in a PKI token.
The client sends some HTTP requests to the server continuously. All things work fine. Now I want to force client (or server) to restart handshaking. In other words, I want to refresh SSL connection which causes to check server certificate periodically. Is there any way to do this? For example, is there any setting to do that periodically or any extension in the certificates which force server/client to restart handshaking?

I know about the session timeout. But this will not refresh the current connection(s). It will force only new connections to do handshaking again.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What is the end goal or security requirement that you think restarting the connection / handshake will solve?

Comment: @Polynomial Actually I want to recheck the USB token (containing the key-pair of the client and trusted certificates) is presented and its content is valid periodically.

Comment: That didn't answer my question. What specific attack are you trying to mitigate?

Comment: @Polynomial I don't think there is a threat to counter here. It's just a reinit to check that the auth token hasn't been changed. It's an "are you still there?" This does not appear to be a security issue at all, but a simple programming question.

Comment: It may be weird, but I do not want to prevent a specific attack. I want the USB token have existed while the client works with the server and if the user rejects the USB token I want to disconnect from the server (after some times).

Comment: @hadi.mansouri if you are ok with sessions expiring, then why not just do a full disconnect/reconnect? Bounce the connection.

Comment: @schroeder To doing this I have to write for example a thread which periodically disconnects/connects the client from/to the server. In this case some request may encounter error. Such exceptions could be prevented if an automatic way exists to repeat handshaking (for example if TLS supports handshake refreshing by setting some configuration).

Comment: I think I understand what you want to do. And I'm really not sure this is a security issue. You want to affect the TCP layer at the app layer and mess with the normal flow. You are looking at custom programming to decrease the security of existing protocols. Cool idea, not a security question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing in the certificate which can be used to implement what you want. Instead that kind of behavior need to be implemented at the client or server: a server can close the current connection and refuse to reuse the previous session, thus causing a full handshake. Similar a client can close the existing connection and not reuse the session which again results in a full handshake.

In theory it would also be possible for either client or server to trigger a new handshake within the existing TCP connection. But it is common that endpoints limit the number of such renegotiations within the same TCP connection in order to protect against TLS renegotiation DoS attacks.

Comment: Thanks. I convinced by this answer.